# Cant' find second instance of jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance

I've been having some problems with a Shopify site that I'm working on. According to Yellow Lab Tools, I have 2 instances of jQuery and that's probably the source of the issue. However, I have installed 1.9.1 in the `<head>` section, then the Yellow Lab Tools says also that there is 2.1.4 installed somewhere on the site.

The site is: www.thehighsociety.com

How can I find where this second instance is, and remove it? Or otherwise tell it to be ignored?

Comment: Seems to be in `http://d2w34ovuwzt349.cloudfront.net/slick.production.min.js?shop=thsths.myshopify.com`

Answer (score 0):

Checked the source of the site. Maybe shopify is already including jquery. Try and comment out version 1.9.1 and see if ti solves the problem.

Another issue I can see is how you are checking if jquery is loaded:

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined')
```

Should be:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
```

[Example here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html)

This may be why the library is loaded twice.

Comment: This did not help, neither did removing the whole code segment (since now that I see I don't think I need it)

Comment: Try and comment the plugins out one by one and see if they are the culprits.

Answer (score 0):

if you remove this piece of code;

```
 <!-- Begin Recently Viewed Products -->
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    //<![CDATA[
    
    // Including jQuery conditionally.
    if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
      document.write("\u003cscript src=\"\/\/ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/1\/jquery.min.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"\u003e\u003c\/script\u003e");
      document.write('<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();<\/script>');
    }
    
    // Including api.jquery.js conditionally.
    if (typeof Shopify.resizeImage === 'undefined') {
      document.write("\u003cscript src=\"\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/assets\/themes_support\/api.jquery-3fdf7f8ecde4022383bde5e52e9d15002ce0866a679c7fa8a02be79b7a21c3ec.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"\u003e\u003c\/script\u003e");
    }
    
    //]]>
  </script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion but this did not solve the problem! ):